# Jquery updating div containt

Tags: html, jquery, ejs

I have 2 div:

- Header div: it contain mor than one button
- Main div: to display the hiden 3 div(s)

The page when start loading i hide the all of the 3 div(s) after that when the user click on the B1 the contant the "main" div must be changed to Div 1 and the same senario for B2 and B3 the problem now when i click on B1 the contant changed normally and when i click on B2 also "but" when i go back to click on button B1 nothing happned. Please i want a clean snippet of code can help me to do that. Thank you

That's my code On loading

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="orderRegulation">
    <%- include('./partitionJob/orderRegulation'); %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="orderRefunded">
    <%- include('./partitionJob/orderRefunded'); %>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#orderRegulation").hide();
        $("#orderRefunded").hide();
    });
</script>
```

When i click on button 1

```
function orderRegulation() {
    $("#row2").replaceWith(jQuery('#orderRegulation').show());
}
```

When i click on button 2

```
function orderRefunded() {
    $("#row2").html(jQuery('#orderRefunded').show());
}
```

Comment: `$(element).replaceWith(newContents)` removes the old element and replaces it with the new contents. `$(element).html(newContents)` replaces the contents of the element, but doesn't remove the element.

Comment: Also, `replaceWith($('#orderRegulation')` moves the `#orderRegulation` DIV, while `.html($('#orderRefunded")` copies the HTML but doesn't move the DIV.

Comment: I already do that but nothing happned.

Comment: please can you give me a snippet of a coorect code if you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the HTML of one DIV into another DIV, use `.html()` to get the original DIV's HTML.

And you should show the element that you're updating, not the template you're copying from.

```
function orderRegulation() {
    $("#row2").html(jQuery('#orderRegulation').html()).show();
}

function orderRefunded() {
    $("#row2").html(jQuery('#orderRefunded').html()).show();
}
```